# Video slider how to automatically playing the next video

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a video slider and would like to be able to switch between the videos but would also like it to automatically play the next video when the previous one is finished. I was looking through the internet for alternative video sliders that automatically play but also are able to be manually controlled but I was without luck so far.

My code:

```js
        function videoUrl(hmmmmmm){
            document.getElementById("slider").src = hmmmmmm;
        }
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing:  border-box;
}

section {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}

section video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 1280px;
    object-fit: cover;
}

section .navigation {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    z-index: 100;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

section .navigation li {
    list-style: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 3px 3px 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

section .navigation li:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

section .navigation li img {
    width: 120px;
    transform: 0.5s;
}

section .navigation li img:hover {
    width: 200px;
}


.dot {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  }
  
  .active, .dot:hover {
    background-color: #717171;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Unbenanntes Dokument</title>
    
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <section>
        <video id="slider" autoplay muted loop>
            <source src="Komp 1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <ul class="navigation">
            <li id="video1" onclick="videoUrl('Komp 1.mp4')"><span class="dot active" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span></li>
            <li id="video2" onclick="videoUrl('Komp 2.mp4')"><span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span></li>
            <li id="video3" onclick="videoUrl('Komp 3.mp4')"><span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span></li>
            <li id="video4" onclick="videoUrl('Komp 4.mp4')"><span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span></li>
            <li id="video5" onclick="videoUrl('Komp 5.mp4')"><span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span></li>
            <li id="video6" onclick="videoUrl('Komp 6.mp4')"><span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(6)"></span></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Solutions I tried:

I tried a onended function that executes the same code as the onclick one

```
video1.onended = function(){
        videoUrl('Komp 2.mp4')
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Videos in slider not playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67884117/videos-in-slider-not-playing)

Comment: Do have a functioning slider? Where's `currentSlide()` defined?

Comment: A lot of browsers block video auto play if the video isn’t muted.

Comment: .oneneded was defined for the video ids

Answer (score 0):

```
<video id="slider" src="Komp 1.mp4" video_id="video1" type="video/mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
<ul class="navigation">
   <li id="video1" onclick="videoUrl('Komp 1.mp4')"><span class="dot active" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span></li>
   <li id="video2" onclick="videoUrl('Komp 2.mp4')"><span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span></li>
   <li id="video3" onclick="videoUrl('Komp 3.mp4')"><span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span></li>
   <li id="video4" onclick="videoUrl('Komp 4.mp4')"><span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span></li>
   <li id="video5" onclick="videoUrl('Komp 5.mp4')"><span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span></li>
   <li id="video6" onclick="videoUrl('Komp 6.mp4')"><span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(6)"></span></li>
</ul>
```

```
document.getElementById('slider').addEventListener('ended',(e) => {
   const video_num = parseInt(e.target.video_id.split('video')[1]);
   document.getElementById('video' + (video_num + 1)).click();
});
```

```
function videoUrl(url){
   const slider = document.getElementById("slider");
   slider.src = url;
   slider.video_id = 'video' + url.substr(5,1);
}
```

Comment: Hello İsa, Wellcome to the Stackoverflow. In SO the answers with some explanation would be appreciated instead of only some code snippets. Don't forget that there are lots of people out there who search similar problems with different levels of experience. Heve fun and "Tekrar Hoşgeldin".

Comment: First of all thank you for your suggestion but it doesn't seem to play the next video once the first one finished.

Comment: @Lupus Thanks for your advice, I'm new here. I'll be more careful next time.